# Click on this element

Tags: excel, vba, webautomation

I need to click on this button with this kind of element:

[image]

This element:

```
<TD title="View the object" class="VDropDown_option" colSpan="2"><NOBR>View</NOBR></TD>
```

My code is:

```
Dim DropDownView As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Set DropDownView = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("VDropDown_option")(0)
        DropDownView.Click
```

In VBA I only have the options GetElementById or ByClassName. But this class is into more than one element, so it doesn't work.

How can I click in this  element?

Comment: I believe querySelector and querySelectorAll are supported in VBA.  Not sure if that will help because I don't know how you are trying to specify the elements, but they are pretty flexible.

Comment: I had a problem, query selector is not supported by IE.

Comment: querySelector is absolutely supported by IE unless you are on <= IE8.  Or messed with your emulation mode. We would also need to know more about the html in order to advise if the attributes of this element are repeated throughout the html. You are also using MSHTML class not IE in the above. Again, this supports querySelector(all).